# Java: Comparing two lists

Tags: java, list

I have two lists. 
For example:

```
A = {21, 41, 96, 02}
B = {21, 96, 32, 952, 1835}
```

What I want is this as a result: `R = {32, 952, 1835}`

Like this: 
[image: Example Picture]

After this I want to add the result `R` to `A`:

```
A = {21, 41, 96, 02, 32, 952, 1835}
```

Comment: How is that going for you?

Comment: Did you wrote any code ? Please, post it.

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: @JamesFox No. Please look at the image. I only want the red part

Comment: are you want to compare these two values ??

Comment: @TheLostMind, oops, I've accidentelly confused order of letters in acronym. what a shame :)

Comment: I am pretty sure this question has many duplicates in stack overflow.

Anyways, seems like you are looking for union, intersection, minus/subtract, etc. stuff, refer to this library `org.apache.commons.collections.ListUtils`

Comment: Guava also has methods for union, intersection, difference, symmetricDifference etc. (http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Sets.html).

Comment: Haskell is good for stuff like this!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's simple :)

```
List<Integer> a = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(21, 41, 96, 02));
List<Integer> b = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(21, 96, 32, 952, 1835));

b.removeAll(a)

// now list b contains (32, 952, 1835)

a.addAll(b);

// now list a contains (21, 41, 96, 02, 32, 952, 1835)
```

Comment: This answers part of the question, finding out `R`.

Comment: @vegemite4me right - I've missed second part - thanks!

Answer (score 1):

So, you want the set reunion of those two collections. That's what [sets](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html) are for.

```
HashSet<Integer> set = new HashSet<Integer>();
set.addAll(a);
set.addAll(b);
```

Answer (score 0):

So you want to make A = A U B. To do this, you can search for each element of B in A and add the element to A if the search fails. However, making too much search on a list is not recommended.

I would recommend using a HashMap. Create a HashMap and loop through A and B putting anything you see into the map. After that, you can convert map back to a list.

[If you want the order to be the same as in the example, you should convert A to a map. Then you should go through B and for each failed map.get(element) you should be adding that element of B to A.]

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
import org.apache.commons.collections.CollectionUtils;

[...]
    //  Returns a Collection containing the exclusive disjunction (symmetric difference) of the given Collections.
    Collection disJointList = CollectionUtils.disjunction(a, b);  
    //To check
    for (Object object : disJointList) {  
            System.out.println(disJointList);  
            //output is {32, 952, 1835} 
    }   

    a.addAll( disJointList );
```